# CListCtrl SetItemData with UINT32 value

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

I have a `CListCtrl` and I want to store a UINT32 value, but it always returns 0 when I read with `GetItemData`

I have this code:

```
UINT CMyDialog::MyThread(LPVOID pArg)
  for (int nItem=0; nItem<50; nItem++)
  {
    UINT32 nNum=100;
    pDlg->m_listCtrl.InsertItem(0, _T("text")); // this works
    pDlg->m_listCtrl.SetItemData(nItem, nNum); // this not
   }
 }

/// this is called from a Dialog member function when a button is pressed

void CMyDialog::OnBtnClicked()
{
  UINT32 nRead=0;
  nRead=m_listCtrl.GetItemData(5);

  // nRead always returns 0
 }
```

Even if I use int or DWORD instead of UINT I get the same result.

Comment: Please post more code as I know this works--I've used it. And a lot of your existing code makes no sense. For example: `m_ListCtrl=GetItemData(nItem)`, how can you assign an integer to a control??? (And start accepting more answers if you want help.)

Comment: this is how it look in my code

Comment: I don't think so. Please see my previous comment

Comment: fixed, sorry, that was a typo here in the post, but not in the code.

Comment: Then shouldn't it be `nRead = m_ListCtrl.GetItemData(5)`?

Comment: sorry, now I have added all the details and fixed that too.

Comment: Sheesh, please learn how to use copy and paste.

Comment: it is not a copy/paste, I have shortened the code for this post.

Comment: It **should** be copy and paste, even if you remove some content for the post. That way, you don't waste everyone's time.

Comment: sorry, next time I'll do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please be more careful posting your code. It's *so* simple to use cut and paste that there is no excuse for making error after error. It's very hard to help you and hardly worth it since you don't accept many answers.

At any rate, I do see a problem with your loop. You should be using the return value from `InsertItem()` like this:

```
UINT CMyDialog::MyThread(LPVOID pArg)
{
    for (int nItem=0; nItem<50; nItem++)
    {
        UINT32 nNum=100;
        int nIndex = pDlg->m_listCtrl.InsertItem(0, _T("text"));
        pDlg->m_listCtrl.SetItemData(nIndex, nNum);
    }
}
```